# Dúvida com views e urls do Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

Qual a melhor forma de fazer essas funções na `views.py`, ou tem que ser assim mesmo?

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/index.html')

def cadastro(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/cadastro-clientes.html')

def contato(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/contato.html')

def sobre(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/quem-somos.html')

def novasenha(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/nova-senha.html')

def base(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/base.html')

def entenda(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/entenda.html')



Quanto a urls.py, também seria a melhor forma deixar meu código da seguinte forma.

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from contas.views import index, cadastro, contato, sobre, novasenha, base, entenda
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('cadastro/', cadastro, name='cadastrar'),
    path('contato/', contato, name='contato'),
    path('sobre/', sobre, name='sobre'),
    path('novasenha/', novasenha, name='novasenha'),
    path('entenda/', entenda, name='entenda'),
    path('', base, name='base')


]
```

Comment: "melhor" em relação a que?

Comment: Tá igual a documentação, o que vc quer melhorar?

Comment: from contas.views import index, cadastro, contato, sobre, novasenha, base, entenda. Aqui, por exemplo: se eu tivesse 30 páginas, teria que inserir todas, é assim mesmo?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, depois do seu comentário, você só quer deixar mais elegante o código no arquivo urls.py.

Em vez de:

```
...
from contas.views import index, cadastro, contato, sobre, novasenha, base, entenda
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('cadastro/', cadastro, name='cadastrar'),
    path('contato/', contato, name='contato'),
    path('sobre/', sobre, name='sobre'),
    ...
]
```

Você pode só importar o arquivo módulo `views` e usa-lo com namespace na declaração:

```
...
from django.urls import path
from contas import views

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', index),
        path('cadastro/', views.cadastro, name='cadastrar'),
        path('contato/', views.contato, name='contato'),
        path('sobre/', views.sobre, name='sobre'),
        ...
    ]
```

E isso aí seria o recomendado.

Se preferir mesmo, não tem mágica, as url_patterns são um objeto Python normalizinho - uma lista de objetos do tipo "path" , onde o primeiro parâmetro é o padrão de url desejado, o segundo o próprio objeto que será a view (que pode ser uma função, uma classe ou outro objeto chamável), e o terceiro, um nome para a view.  Ou seja: você pode gerar essa lista programaticamente a partir de introspecção do módulo "views" - em vez de declarar todas de forma estática no arquivo. É um caso em que em geral "explícito" é melhor que implícito - mas pode te poupar ter que editar um arquivo a mais cada vez que criar uma view nova - nesse caso, o código pode ser algo do tipo:

```
from contas import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', index),
]

for name, obj in views.__dict__.items():
    if callable(obj):
        urlpatterns.append(path(f"{name}/", obj, name)
```

Com esse código, todas as funções no seu arquivo "views" vão ter uma URL gerada automaticamente.

Perceba que enquanto isso é uma prática meio perigosa, uma vez que não distingue funções que você pode não querer usar como views, e etc..., a técnica permite perceber como é simples fazer algo no Django para ser usado como um "decorador para views", como é feito em outros frameworks, como o Flask.

No caso, pode ser um decorador bem simples, que não "envelopa" a função decorada, apenas acrescenta a ela os dados desejados:

```
def autoview(path=None, name=None):
    def decorate(func):
         # acrescenta o atributo "autoview" na função, 
         # que é um objeto Python normal:

         func.autoview = {
             "path": path or f"{func.__name__}/",
             "name": name or func.__name__
         }
         return func
    return decorate
```

Dai você pode escrever seu arquivo de views nesse estilo:

```
from utils import autoview
...

@autoview(name="cadastrar")
def cadastro(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/cadastro-clientes.html')

@autoview()
def contato(request):
    return render(request, 'contas/contato.html')
```

E no urls.py, uma variante da sugestão acima, para usar o ".autoview":

```
for name, obj in views.__dict__.items():
    if hasattr(object, "autoview"):
        urlpatterns.append(path(obj.autoview["path"], obj, obj.autoview["name"])
```

Comment: Pelo que compreende, não seria uma boa pratica fazer dessa forma que você apresentou porque, pode alguém conseguir inserir outro arquivo? exemplo www.meusite.com/ataque.html Seria isso? alguém inseriu um html ataque e ele iria aceitar?

Comment: Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Outra ajuda, se possível. como faria para o django alterar o title de cada página. Ex: quando clicar em cadastro, ele alterava o title do html para página de cadastro.

Comment: Django não é PHP - não tem como alguém inserir um arquivo no servidor se não conseguir acesso ao servidor por outros meios.   Se a pessoa já tem acesso ao servidor com permissão para criar arquivos onde está a app, tanto faz precisar de um arquivo só ou não em termos de segurança. As sugestões aqui não tem nenhum impacto do ponto de vista de segurança - e a última é uma receitinha para usar o paradgima de view por decorador, que é comume m outros frameworks, também no django.

Comment: Para o "title" é só usar o tag html `<title>` no seu template de HTML, e preenche-lo com alguma variável da view, como faz com qualquer outro dado.